# c# linq search with nested list and struct

Tags: c#, linq, nested, ienumerable

i have a struct

```
public struct one_point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int _value{ get; set; }
}
```

and 2 lists

```
List<one_point> rotation_list = new List<one_point>();
List<List<one_point>> Full_list = new List<List<one_point>>();
```

if i want a `List<one_point> result`
which is a list of all the points with a _value less than 50

how do i query it ? something like ;

```
IEnumerable<one_point> result = Full_list.Where(y => y.SelectMany(z => z._value < 50));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the list **before** making any conditional checks on it.

```
IEnumerable<one_point> result = Full_list.SelecetMany(x => x).Where(x => x._value < 50);
```